# Issue with Heroku's production configuration: a set of two dynos takes 8 seconds to respond

Tags: heroku, dyno

I have an interrogation regarding Heroku's dynos.

As of now my app runs two 512MB dynos and I was pretty certain that this configuration, i.e. more than one dyno, ensured that the container's application was started and ready to serve clients.

However, I frequently notice that the dynos are not always started and it takes something like 8 seconds to load the app. See screen shot below. The host XXXX.herokuapp.com spends nearly 8 seconds in "waiting".

Has anyone else experienced such issues with Heroku? How can they be resolved?

[image: screen shot]